# Assigning window.parent.location.href = window.location.href

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

My page contains two iframes. Both iframes represents a single page applications that contain routes for different views.

E.g.

parent window (contains the iframes): http://mypage.com

iframe1: http://mypage.com/#case/1

iframe2: http://mypage.com/#register/2

Each iframe contains a button that, when clicked, should display the entire iframe content in the iframe parent's window.

Now I wanted to assign the href attribute of an iframe's location object to the iframe's parent location object:

```
window.parent.location.href = window.location.href;
```

This code is executed inside the iframe obviously. But when executing it , the iframe reloads http://mypage.com. The parent window doesn't get reloaded at all.

Comment: If you put `http://mypage.com/#case/1` in the address bar, can you actually go there?

Comment: Yes. The views can be accessed by the parent window as well as by iframes.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the parent frame didn't reload by assigning a new URL to window.parent.location.

Additionally, I had to call reload() to get the page doing an actual reload.

```
window.parent.location.reload();
```